# Show only specific data to users in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I've got a database with following structure:

`{username: {dataset_name: {dataset...}}}`

User can share datasets with other users. My idea is to have a key, like "SharedWith" in each dataset, which contains a list of usernames.

Then a View should take care that the users only see their own datasets and the datasets which are shared with them.
Is this possible with mongodb?

How could I realize that?

**Update**
Ok, as I've seen so far a backend is needed to provide the functionality which I need. I thought the DB itself could provide this, but it seems that I was wrong.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, as you can choose to show/filter whatever you want. I suggest editing your question to show some representative data, along with your MongoDB query, along with expected vs actual behavior. As written, there's really no question to answer.

Comment: The reason why I need this is that the client application is running on the local machine (it is not a web application) and the user should not be able to fetch any data from the database which is not shared with him, even if he hacks the application or writes his own client. The filtering should be done on the server side and the user should not be able to modify these filters.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're talking about regarding 'hacking' the application, but yes you should be doing some type of server-side API/service that then accesses the database for your app, instead of direct-connecting to the database. The issue here, though, is that you haven't shown any specific details, or any effort of your own. You can't just post a set of requirements and then ask the Community to implement something for you (well you *can* but that typically leads to downvotes, closure, and deletion fairly quickly).

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution using mongoose. No view required.

```js
import mongoose from "mongoose"

const url = "mongodb://127.0.0.1/TestProject"

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   _id: {
      type: Number,
   },
   username: {
      type: String,
   },
   dataset: {
      type: mongoose.Mixed, // or define it explicitly if schema is known
   },
   sharedWith: [{
      type: Number,
      ref: "User2"
   }]
})
const User = mongoose.model('User2', userSchema)


mongoose.connect(url)
        .then(addData)
        .then(() => getDatasets(1))
        .then(console.log)
        .then(() => getDatasets(2))
        .then(console.log)
        .catch(console.error)

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

async function addData () {
   const data = [
      {_id: 1, username: "andy", dataset: {likesIcecream: true, credits: 23}, sharedWith: []},
      {_id: 2, username: "berta", dataset: {likesIcecream: false, credits: 1000}, sharedWith: [1]},
   ]
   for (const d of data) {
      await User.findOneAndUpdate({_id: d._id}, d, {upsert: true})
   }
}

async function getDatasets (userId) {
   const user = await User.findById(userId).populate("sharedWith")
   return {
      username: user.username,
      datasets: [user.dataset, ...user.sharedWith.map(u => u.dataset)]
   }
}
```

When running this script the output is:

```
{
  username: 'andy',
  datasets: [ { likesIcecream: true, credits: 23 } ]
}
{
  username: 'berta',
  datasets: [
    { likesIcecream: false, credits: 1000 },
    { likesIcecream: true, credits: 23 }    
  ]
}
```

So as you can see the datasets of Users get included into the list of result datasets if a `sharedWith` entry is present.